# Execute function when div height changes

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div that changes in height based on the content (its width is fixed).

I want to execute a function each time this automatic change in div height occurs.

Can someone please help me achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

*EDIT:*
The div height changes when I drag and drop some content on the div. (I am using JQuery UI draggable-droppable). So, the change in height is user initiated.

Comment: You will need to run a check if height has changed every time you change the content of the `div` or properties that might change the size of the content (`font-size`, `line-height`, etc). The `onresize` event exists only for the `window` object, not for document elements.

Comment: I know that w3schools isn't the most reliable resource, but it claims that the div tag does support it. Is it wrong? - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

Comment: After [testing it out](http://jsfiddle.net/maPWM/1/), it looks like in IE, the `<div>` tag supports it, but not in FF. I only tested those two, but if it doesn't work in FF, then it's not an acceptable solution, and w3schools is proven wrong again.

Comment: The only reliable solution is what lanzz said. *When* exactly do the height changes occur?

Comment: The div height changes when new content is added; the width remains fixed.

Comment: @lanzz: by 'run a check if height has changed', are you referring to the some kind of polling as done in this plugin: (http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/docs/files/jquery-ba-resize-js.html)? If so, this is something I want to avoid due to the potential performance issues...

Comment: No. I mean that there is no way for new content to appear in that `div`, except if some javascript code adds it there. So, every time your javascript adds content to the `div`, you should check if its height with the new content is different from its height before you changed the content, and if it is, invoke your function. You could bind to the [`drop` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop) on your droppable.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve you may not need to capture a resize. You may want to elaborate.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to change the height of a second div when the height of the first one increases/decreases. So, the height of the second div will increase or decrease based on the height of the first div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an excellent solution here, created by the Filament group: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/ - please do not click this; it seems the resource has been removed.

Comment: Posting pages to sites outside of StackOverflow are not good acceptable answers since there is no control over if the page is no longer available like this one is now.